# Playing sound on a button click

Tags: iphone

I'm facing a very strange issue, my requirement is to play a sound on the button click and this is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button-3" ofType:@"mp3"];
    tapSound=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]];
    [tapSound prepareToPlay];
    tapSound.delegate=self;

    //creating the button in view did load and button is declared in .h
    btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 58,58);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClkd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

//click method
-(void)btnClkd:(UIButton*)sender
{
[tapSound play];
}
```

But when I run the code and click the button my app gets crashed and got this error:  "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton play]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x758c790' "

But if I play the sound anywhere else but not on the click of the button then it get played without any issue.I dont know why this is happening? Please help me

Comment: try the button by allocing it.

i am not sure but just give it a try by this way.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
-(void)btnClkd:(UIButton*)sender
{
   NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button-3" ofType:@"mp3"];
   tapSound = nil;
   tapSound=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]];
   [tapSound prepareToPlay];
   tapSound.delegate=self;
   [tapSound play];
}
```

Comment: I know it will work but why it gives an issue when we define AVAudioPlayer object in view did load??

Answer (score 0):

Try this one . Add in your .h file

```
 .h file 



         #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
            #import <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>


        AVAudioPlayer *player1;

        @property(nonatomic ,retain)AVAudioPlayer *player1;

in your .m file 




@synthesize  player1;



    - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];    

 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];    
            NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button-3" ofType:@"mp3"];    
            NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];    
            AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];    
            [fileURL release]; 
            self.player1 = audioPlayer;    
            [audioPlayer release]; 
           [self.player1 prepareToPlay];
          [self.player1 setDelegate:self];
           [pool release]; 

            //creating the button in view did load and button is declared in .h
            btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            btn.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 58,58);
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClkd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview:btn];
        }




    -(void)btnClkd:(UIButton*)sender {            

            [self.player1 play];

    }
```

Comment: try to the this way (i have edit my ans.) may be played or try to the device

Comment: already done in that way, but dont know why it always get crashed(talking about simulator), seems to be an ios issue, let me also post my whole code, I might be doing some silly mistake